# Dialog Flow CX Custom Entity Not Working As Condition on page

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I created a new custom entity called `ptype` with values `"existing"` and `"new"`, no synonym turned on.

Then on a page I have no intent, I set in parameters the display name as `patient_type`
For entity i choose my custom entity: `@ptype`
required turned on

and lastly on routes i set:

```
"Match AT LEAST ONE rule (OR)"
```

parameter: `$session.params.patient_type`
operator: `=`
value: `"existing"`

lastly at the end of the page for transition I put the page I want it to transition to.

When I try it in the simulator it will show me a box

> patient_type [original: "existing"] ADDED

but it wont transition, status in logs is transitioning..

Iv tried recreating my whole bot and everything, all the pages, entities, renaming it all, tried all the different types of variables like `$pages.params`, `$session.params`, `$patient_type = "existing`"

nothing worked... i had to use `sys.any` and it worked... But i want to use my own entities..

Answer (score 1):

You have a entity called ptype with two values "existing" and "new". Your problem is that you don't have synonym added.

In [the documentation of DialogFlow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity-options) is explained that it is necessary a synonym of each option. The name "existing" or "new" is the reference value, then in the route you could do `$session.params.patient_type="existing"` but you need to put as least "existing" as synonym of this value. So to speak, we could say that one thing (the reference name) is the key of a map, and the synonym is the value of the map.

> Notice that the reference value is included in the synonym list for each entity entry above. In order for a reference value to be matched, it needs to be included as a synonym itself

Answer (score 0):

you should try $intent.params.patient_type

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
$session.params.p_type = existing
```

no quotation marks.